# Internal Server Error djangosaml2 login from React-Native Webview

Tags: django, react-native, saml

Error Message: "Internal Server Error: /saml2/acs/"

Connecting to my IdP using React-Natives Webview Component. 
After logging in, I am beeing redirected to my website, and the djangosaml2 library should log in the user. Here I get the Internal server error.

The login is working when using chrome, but not from the React-Native app. (Android emulator)

I am using react-native-cookies, and all the cookies seems to be deleted when redirected to my website.

I tried setting allow_unsolicited : True, under SAML_CONFIG, but it did not work.

```
    'service': {
    # we are just a lonely SP
    'sp' : {
        "allow_unsolicited" : True,
         # Other stuff here
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

---

The whole error message:

```
Internal Server Error: /saml2/acs/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tpweb/webapps/dev_tpdjango/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 132, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/tpweb/webapps/dev_tpdjango/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/http.py", line 45, in inner
    return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tpweb/webapps/dev_tpdjango/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tpweb/webapps/dev_tpdjango/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/djangosaml2/views.py", line 253, in assertion_consumer_service
    outstanding_queries)
  File "/home/tpweb/webapps/dev_tpdjango/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/saml2/client_base.py", line 597, in parse_authn_request_response
    binding, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tpweb/webapps/dev_tpdjango/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/saml2/entity.py", line 1140, in _parse_response
    response = response.loads(xmlstr, False, origxml=origxml)
  File "/home/tpweb/webapps/dev_tpdjango/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/saml2/response.py", line 534, in loads
    "Unsolicited response: %s" % self.in_response_to)
saml2.response.UnsolicitedResponse: Unsolicited response: None

Request repr():
<WSGIRequest
path:/saml2/acs/,
GET:<QueryDict: {}>,
POST:{'RelayState': 'https://tptest.teknologiporten.no/',
 'SAMLResponse': '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'},
COOKIES:{},
META:{'CONTENT_LENGTH': '6951',
 'CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
 'CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT': '/usr/local/apache2/htdocs',
 'CONTEXT_PREFIX': '',
 'CSRF_COOKIE': 'mzZklkdIAK6yok6KSBO0DOl2IVsWQ2Sl',
 'DOCUMENT_ROOT': '/usr/local/apache2/htdocs',
 'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI/1.1',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip, deflate',
 'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL': 'max-age=0',
 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'close',
 'HTTP_FORWARDED_REQUEST_URI': '/saml2/acs/',
 'HTTP_HOST': 'tptest.teknologiporten.no',
 'HTTP_HTTPS': 'on',
 'HTTP_ORIGIN': 'https://idp-test.feide.no',
 'HTTP_REFERER': 'https://idp-test.feide.no/simplesaml/module.php/preprodwarning/showwarning.php?StateId=_a037e0ea1078b06b76e1f3b4d0af80da8487218584%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fidp-test.feide.no%2Fsimplesaml%2Fsaml2%2Fidp%2FSSOService.php%3Fspentityid%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Ftptest.teknologiporten.no%252Fsaml2%252Fmetadata%252F%26cookieTime%3D1522761547%26RelayState%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Ftptest.teknologiporten.no%252F&yes=',
 'HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS': '1',
 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Android SDK built for '
                    'x86 Build/MASTER; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like '
                    'Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/44.0.2403.119 Mobile '
                    'Safari/537.36',
 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR': '109.189.22.180',
 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST': 'tptest.teknologiporten.no',
 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO': 'https',
 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER': 'tptest.teknologiporten.no',
 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL': 'on',
 'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH': 'com.temp_tp',
 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH': '/home/tpweb/webapps/dev_tpdjango/apache2/lib:/home/tpweb/webapps/dev_tpdjango/lib',
 'PATH_INFO': '/saml2/acs/',
 'PATH_TRANSLATED': '/home/tpweb/webapps/dev_tpdjango/tp-django/teknologiporten/wsgi.py/saml2/acs/',
 'QUERY_STRING': '',
 'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1',
 'REMOTE_PORT': '43212',
 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST',
 'REQUEST_SCHEME': 'http',
 'REQUEST_URI': '/saml2/acs/',
 'SCRIPT_FILENAME': '/home/tpweb/webapps/dev_tpdjango/tp-django/teknologiporten/wsgi.py',
 'SCRIPT_NAME': '',
 'SERVER_ADDR': '127.0.0.1',
 'SERVER_ADMIN': '[no address given]',
 'SERVER_NAME': 'tptest.teknologiporten.no',
 'SERVER_PORT': '80',
 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0',
 'SERVER_SIGNATURE': '',
 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'Apache/2.4.23 (Unix) mod_wsgi/4.5.9 Python/3.5',
 'apache.version': (2, 4, 23),
 'mod_wsgi.application_group': 'web570.webfaction.com|',
 'mod_wsgi.callable_object': 'application',
 'mod_wsgi.daemon_connects': '1',
 'mod_wsgi.daemon_restarts': '0',
 'mod_wsgi.daemon_start': '1522761549597121',
 'mod_wsgi.enable_sendfile': '0',
 'mod_wsgi.handler_script': '',
 'mod_wsgi.ignore_activity': '0',
 'mod_wsgi.listener_host': '',
 'mod_wsgi.listener_port': '22330',
 'mod_wsgi.path_info': '/saml2/acs/',
 'mod_wsgi.process_group': 'tpdjango',
 'mod_wsgi.queue_start': '1522761549596951',
 'mod_wsgi.request_handler': 'wsgi-script',
 'mod_wsgi.request_id': 'SMg9jZln+gE',
 'mod_wsgi.request_start': '1522761549596744',
 'mod_wsgi.script_name': '',
 'mod_wsgi.script_reloading': '1',
 'mod_wsgi.script_start': '1522761549597271',
 'mod_wsgi.thread_id': 1,
 'mod_wsgi.thread_requests': 26,
 'mod_wsgi.total_requests': 52,
 'mod_wsgi.version': (4, 5, 8),
 'wsgi.errors': <_io.TextIOWrapper encoding='utf-8'>,
 'wsgi.file_wrapper': <class 'mod_wsgi.FileWrapper'>,
 'wsgi.input': <mod_wsgi.Input object at 0x7fe8d4b48f10>,
```